# How to make comment around a line of description using vim?

Tags: c, vim, comments

I thought it would be handy to create a mapping that would turn the current line or visually selected line into a comment banner.

Something like this:

```
This is the description of the usage of the class
```

would become, after pressing a shortcut:

```
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
/* This is the description of the usage of the class  */
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
```

Comment: @kev `tcomment` is very cool, but I don't know how to make the a shaped comment which looks fancy and easier to identify. Is this a good habit to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have this line in my `~/.vimrc` that does exactly what you want:

```
nnoremap <leader>g I/* <Esc>A */<Esc>yyp0llv$r-$hc$*/<Esc>yykPjj
```

Place your cursor on a line, press `<leader>g`, done.

The default `<leader>` is `\`, so that would be `\g`.

You can, obviously, use any shortcut you want.